# Interference between two beams of unpolarized light

Tags: optics, diffraction

Interference is explained by showing a diagram of two parallel waves of light that are in phase or out of phase and showing the result of the fields constructively or destructively interfering. Implicitly it seems to be the case that they are polarised in the same plane as well. What I wanted to know is what this picture looks like when we're talking about unpolarised light.

I'm reading about XRD and Bragg's, and can't seem to find any indication that polarised X-rays are used. And if that isn't the case, then even if two waves are in phase, the net E fields are polarised in random directions to each other and wouldn't undergo constructive interference. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Yes, we often do experiments with unpolarised light and it should have implications on the interference-ability. However, we often start with single sources, and those sources have finite temporal and thus also spatial coherence, despite being unpolarised over longer timescales. This is sufficient to generate the interference patterns. And yes, this is one of those things that is omitted from texts and so forth, and you will only get them if you asked a prof who happens to know.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Even if those sources are coherent, that still doesn't mean light emitted from them is plane-polarized right? What I'm confused about is I feel like two randomly polarised waves even if in phase wouldn't necessarily constructively interfere

Comment: There is no need for the light to be plane-polarised. Circularly polarised light will interfere just as well, and is indeed even easier to visualise the interference than planar polarisation. They might be randomly polarised over longer time-scales, but within the coherence times, there would be _some_ polarisation in which they can be parametrised, and constructively interfere there.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Circularly polarised light interfering makes sense to me. If the helices are in phase or 'aligned' it makes sense that the E and M fields add. I'm not sure I completely understood what you said there at the end though about there being 'some polarisation in which they can be parameterised'

Comment: Im saying that I don't care if it is circularly polarised or linearly polarised or elliptically polarised, the unpolarised light will be, for short times, polarised enough in one of those ways to allow the interference to happen.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Ah, alright, got it. So the source of light we typically use is somewhat polarized (within the time scales of the experiment)

Comment: Not somewhat polarised; unpolarised light itself is typically polarised on very short time scales, but just enough to do interference with.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Ah, okay. Understood. Thank you

Comment: You can think of “interference” as the ability of the EM field to allow passage of energy. In the double slit experiment there is no energy in the dark bands, all energy (photons) are in the bright areas. Photons never “interfere” with each other, I.e. we can never see the superposition of em fields, we just observe photons on paths the em field has permitted upon absorption.

Answer (score 0):

> Interference is explained by showing a diagram of two parallel waves of light that are in phase or out of phase and showing the result of the fields constructively or destructively interfering.

The way you present it, you won't be able to create interference. Your description must include the passage of light rays through a slit.

> Implicitly it seems to be the case that they are polarised in the same plane as well.

Experience indeed shows that (the surroundings of) the edges of the slit cause polarisation of the light.

> What I wanted to know is what this picture looks like when we're talking about unpolarised light.

The incident light does not have to be monochrome or in phase:

- with polychrome light, more blurred intensity stripes are created
- a series of single photons also creates a fringe pattern on an observation screen
- light is also diffracted at a single edge and the incident areas of the light are also of varying intensity.

> I … can't seem to find any indication that polarised (X-)rays are used. And if that isn't the case, then even if two waves are in phase, the net E fields are polarised in random directions to each other and wouldn't undergo constructive interference. Where am I going wrong here?

In that you have not included the influence of the rays by edges or, in the case of X-rays, by the atomic structures of the crystal in your considerations.

Comment: I don't understand why the is slit necessary for interference as you've mentioned in the first paragraph? The planes of the crystal will reflect the plane wave incident on them, and the reflected waves interfere. Also, can you have a look at the explanation given to me in the comments of the question, i.e that unpolarized light on short time scales is polarized. The explanation you've given is the edges of the slit cause polarization

Comment: Also, with regard to your first paragraph point, if I had two plane waves parallel to each other, wouldn't there be superposition

Comment: What else is a polariser grid but a set of edges?

Comment: Alright. I still don't understand why plane waves can't constructively add i.e the necessity of a slit: "The way you present it, you won't be able to create interference. Your description must include the passage of light rays through a slit."